# align a div below some content and position footer at the bottom of div

Tags: php, html, css

Hello I have two problems...If you look at my picture the submit button that says "add to cart" should be below pictures and the gray footer with my name should be at the bottom of the page, I have spent an hour trying to figure out how to do this and I don't know how..
I am using a php function that has the pictures save with a class of .bookdetails and the submit button id is .cart....footer is just footer..I need to do this...can you please help...here is how my page looks like 
[image]

Here is my code for diplaying the pictures

```
for($row = 0; $row < sizeof($array);$row++){
  echo '<div class="book-details"><img src="images/'.$array[$row]['isbn'].'.jpg" alt="'.$array[$row]['title'].'" >'.'<br/>'.$array[$row]['title'].'<br/>by '.$array[$row]['author'].'<br/><input type="radio" name="orders['.$array[$row]['title'].']" value="hardcover" >Hardcover: $'.$array[$row]['hardcover'].'<br/><input type="radio" name="orders['.$array[$row]['title'].']" value="softcover" >Softcover: $'.$array[$row]['softcover'].'<br/><input type="radio" name="orders['.$array[$row]['title'].']" value="e-book" >E-Book: $'.$array[$row]['e-book']."</div>";
};
echo '<div class = "cart"><input  type="submit" value="Add Selected Items   to        Cart"></div>';
echo '</form>';
```

Here is my css

```
.book-details {
    width:auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;


} 
.cart{

     width:auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    float: right;

}
```

can you help me put the add selected items below the pictures and the footer below that? thanks

Comment: Something like this? [Example](http://jsbin.com/lozowe/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing .book-details display to block.

And for the footer try this:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height:100px;
}
```